# How can I save email attachments to the server in PHP?

Tags: php, email, mime

I've been battling PHP's email reading functions for the better part of two days. I'm writing a script to read emails from a mailbox and save any attachments onto the server. If you've ever done something similar, you might understand my pain: **PHP doesn't play well with email!**

I've connected to the POP3 server and I can iterate the files. Here's a rough outline of the code:

```
if (!$mbox = imap_open ("{myserver.com:110/pop3/notls}INBOX", "u", "p"))
    die ('Cannot connect/check mail! Exiting');

if ($hdr = imap_check($mbox)) 
    $msgCount = $hdr->Nmsgs;
else 
    die ("Failed to get mail");

foreach ($overview as $message) {
    $msgStruct = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $message->msgno);

    // if it has parts, there are attachments that need reading
    if ($msgStruct->parts) {
        foreach ($msgStruct->parts as $key => $part) {
            switch (strtoupper($part->subtype)) {
                case 'GIF': case 'JPEG':case 'PNG':

                    //do something - but what?!

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've marked where I'm stuck. I can use `imap_fetchbody($mbox, $message->msgno, $key+1)` but that gets me a bunch of data like this:

```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...
```

I'm lead to believe that this is MIME data. I need it as an image! I've seen several classes bombing around the internet that claim to do the required wizardry. I can't get any of them to work. I don't understand why I'm finding this so hard!

**In short**, I'm looking for something that can turn a raw MIME string into real data.

Comment: have you checked what's the attachment encoding?

Comment: Hi Dr Nick (i just had to) But yes, MIME data is base 64 encoded. So ben is correct.

Comment: hey can you post a more complete snippet? i can't seem to get it to work bc im not sure where $overview is coming from

Comment: I have the same problem as yours. I found some good article, and I think it might help you
http://www.linuxscope.net/articles/mailAttachmentsPHP.html
enjoy it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a quick guide how to treat emails with PHP: [here](http://www.linuxscope.net/articles/mailAttachmentsPHP.html).

At the bottom of that page there's a attachment-body `echo`:

```
if (substr($ContentType,0,4) == "text") {
echo imap_qprint($fileContent);
} else {
echo imap_base64($fileContent);
}
```

I guess this is what you might need...

(edit: in your case if it's image always you can skip the `if` part. And of course, save the file instead of echoing it:)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Yeah I'm already doing the content-type-detection (with my switch-statement) so I only needed the imap_base64.

Answer (score 1):

MIME data is base-64 encoded, so I think you should be able to decode it using base64_decode

Answer (score 1):

you can use the  [`imap_base64`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-base64.php)  function  and just output that to a file, or use  [`imap_savebody`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-savebody.php)

Comment: imap_savebody (from my recent experience) saves the encoded data (just as if you ran fetchbody)

Answer (score 1):

Zend framework contains Zend_Mail, which should make reading mail messages much easier, and Zend_Mime, which I believe can parse a multipart mime message into a sensible data structure.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html

Comment: I'd love to be able to deploy on the Zend Framework but hosting limitations restrict it. It's a real pity because the mail-reading functionality in plain PHP is twisted beyond all logical comprehension.

Comment: Is it the size of the framework that's holding you back? Our web apps bundle zend framework for when it's not available on the customer's web server.