# Using PHP to save an inbound e-mail attachments to disk

Tags: php, email, mime, pipe, email-attachments

I am looking to write a PHP script that I can pipe an email too. The script then extracts all attachments and saves them to a folder on the server, discarding the message.

I have found many examples to read the email as a string which can be split up:

```
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
```

However non of these handle the extraction of mime attachments. I have had a look at the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php#96414) but with no luck on seeing how to slot it all together.

Is there an easy way to do this, it is even possible using pipes rather than a pop account?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162576/how-can-i-save-email-attachments-to-the-server-in-php

Comment: I saw this however it is using a pop3 account and not piped email

Answer (score 0):

> it is even possible using pipes rather than a pop account?

That's got nothing to do with how you handle the structure of the message itself. To answer the question of how to read the message sybchronously instead of polling, we'd need to know what OS this is on and how the MDA is configured (hint: if its Unix/Linux/POSIX, use procmail).

A description of how you go about paring the body of the email goes way beyond an answer here - but you can find lots of ready made solution on the internet. e.g. [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html)

Comment: From my research the built in php objects will retrieve a message from pop3 or imap account that is already parsed where I only have a string hence my question. I was unsure how the OS and MDA were relevant as a piped message (in this case with cpannel) is delivered to the script already as a stream without need to poll. However the link to the parser may work - Thanks